# deactivate a process builder

Tags: apex

We have a process builder that is interfering with another data sync process.

Is there a way to deactivate the process builder programmatically using apex code?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a hierarchical Custom Settings field `Run_Process`, set to `false` for a specific user that runs that data sync and include this into each step's criteria for the process (or have one at the top like `Run_Process = false` to exit the process)